# What the best way or lib for creating thumbnail from memory stream (video) in C#?

Tags: c#, video, dll, movie, video-thumbnails

I have to create multiple thumbnails and save on amazon s3 in c#. I don't find library which can create thumbnail from memory stream only from source file. But can't have file source, I have only the stream from the upload and I don't want save localy the file.

Thx for ur help!

Answer (score 1):

Simple c# code can do this for you. You can create a thumbnail from byte array.
First convert your memory stream object to byte array by following code

```
byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

and then you can use below method

```
public byte[] MakeThumbnail(byte[] myImage, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (Image thumbnail = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(myImage)).GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null, new IntPtr()))
    {
        thumbnail.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: But Image.FromStream throws an ArgumentException when the stream is not an image. OP asked for when the stream is a video.

Answer (score -2):

> I don't find library which can create thumbnail from memory stream only from 
>   source file

Really? Because I do not need a library for that - I can do that with standard C#.

System.Drawing.Bitmap has a constructor accepting a stream.

> But can't have file source,

Actually you can - it is called a temporary file and there is a whole mechanism for that in .NET (and windows). Really.

But it is not needed. Read the manual, create a bitmap (by packing your byte array into a MemoryStream) and it should work.

Comment: Thx for the response but I want create thumbnail from movie file not img file.

Comment: @Yvan did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same dilemna.